# Getting x509 error while using hoverfly in capture mode

Tags: java, spring-boot, automated-tests, x509, resttemplate

I have a spring-boot application for which i am writing integration tests

I'm trying to use hoverfly-java to capture the traffic for an external system i am using. My test runs fine when i dont add hoverfly, but on adding this line:

```
@ClassRule
public static HoverflyRule hoverflyRule = HoverflyRule.inCaptureOrSimulationMode("simulation.json");
```

My external system returns a 500 and I see the following error

**POST abc/login: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**

How to I update my resttemplate to fix this?

Comment: Hoverfly uses a self signed certificate between the client and itself, and then the server certificate between itself and and the external service. It essentially does a mitm attack. The reason you shouldn't get an error is because the Java binding temporarily adds Hoverflies self signed certificate to the trust store during the test run. So your error should not happen. Does your external service use a self-signed certificate too?

Comment: @mogronalol How do I determine if my external service is using a self signed certificate? It works completely fine without hoverfly

Comment: Does this work? 

echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername gnupg.org -connect gnupg.org:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text

Comment: Obviously with your server name

Comment: echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -https://example.com gnupg.org -connect gnupg.org:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text
unable to load certificate
12592:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Answer (score 1):

Actally, rather than me asking questions I can guess that if it is the case of being self-signed, you can try using the `-tls-verification` command in Hoverfly as documented here:

http://hoverfly.readthedocs.io/en/v0.13.0/pages/reference/hoverfly/hoverflycommands.html?highlight=tls

However, I have noticed that this is not configurable through Hoverfly Java. Try using the Hoverfly binary directly to prove that it is indeed the fix, and if that is the case raise a GitHub issue and we will make it configurable in the Java binding.

Comment: What is the server you are connecting to? Is it available on the public internet?

Comment: Nope, it is my company's internal, It is an avamar instance

Comment: GET scheme:https destination:example.com path:/example/1234  query:map[] headers:map[Req.id.filter.prefix:[req.id.filter.prefix] 
 X-Src_appname:[app-v1.0.0]
 Authorization:[Digest username="***", realm="***", nonce="***", uri="***", response="***", qop=auth, nc=***, cnonce="***", algorithm=MD5] 
 Accept:[application/json, application/xml, application/json, application/*+json, text/xml, application/*+xml, application/*+json] 
 Connection:[Keep-Alive] 
 User-Agent:[Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_72)] 
 Accept-Encoding:[gzip,deflate]]] [34mresponse[0m=&map[error:nil response]

Comment: Tried for another external service, got a different error

Comment: Do you have an example service that I can reproduce this with which is available on the public internet? That way I can repeat your steps locally and determine whether it's a bug or a misconfiguration.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling TLS verification solved the issue for me.
May be you didn't try the correct command.

Try `hoverfly -tls-verification=false`

You should see `TLS certificate verification has been disabled`
in the logs.
Hope this helps.